# Set perl cgi query_string offline

Tags: perl, cgi, param, modulino

I'd like to write some unit tests for my cgi script. I wrote my script as a modulino (script which could be a module depending on context) and I would like to test its functionality but also make sure that all parameters in query_string are set as they should.

I'd tried doing something like this:

```
$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'} = 'param1=some_param';
my $cgi = CGI->new;
print "param1= ".$cgi->param("param1")."\n";
```

But it seems to be completely ignoring that. Is there a way to set a query string without actually doing GET method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line arguments with CGI.pm.

```
$ index.pl param1=some_param foo=bar
```

Those will show up in the script. But that is still inconvenient for unittesting your application. If there is a webserver there anyway, you can use [Test::WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/Test::WWW::Mechanize).

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution:

```
$ENV{QUERY_STRING} = 'engine=sample';
$ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} = 'GET';
$ENV{GATEWAY_INTERFACE} = 'CGI/1.1';
```

Apparentely `$ENV{QUERY_STRING}` is not enough for this to work.